# Use boolean series of different length to select rows from dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"piece": ["piece1", "piece2", "piece3", "piece4"], "No": [1, 1, 2, 3]})

  No   piece
0   1  piece1
1   1  piece2
2   2  piece3
3   3  piece4
```

I have a series with an index that corresponds to the "No"-column in the dataframe. It assigns boolean variables to the "No"-values, like so:

```
s = pd.Series([True, False, True, True])

0     True
1    False
2     True
3     True
dtype: bool
```

I would like to select those rows from the dataframe where in the series the "No"-value is True. This should result in

```
  No   piece
2   2  piece3
3   3  piece4
```

I've tried a lot of indexing with df["No"].isin(s), or something like df[s["No"] == True]... But it didn't work yet.

Comment: Are you looking for `df[s]`?

Comment: @Psidom. I would say turn that into an answer, but you shouldn't answer a question with another question unless you need to boost your character count :)

Comment: No, but I see how my example looks that way. The problem is that in df, multiple rows may have the same "No"-value, and that this value is not the same as the index. I'll edit my question to represent the actual question better.

Comment: @KoraK It sounds exatcly what you're asking for. "I would like to select those rows from the dataframe where in the series the "No"-value is True". Also, your (edited) expected output contradicts that statement.

Comment: Just to clarify, `No` is supposed to match the index of `s`, right?

Comment: With df[s], I get those rows where the index of df is mapped to True by the series. I want those rows where "No" of df is mapped to True by the series.

Comment: @KoraK: There are three `True`s in `s` but in your desired outcome are only two rows. Why is that?

Comment: Yes, in the series, the index is "No", in df it has its separate column.

Comment: @Cleb: There are three `True`s in `s`. 0 doesn't matter because no row in df has "No"=0, and there are two rows with each "No" 2 and 3, those should be returned.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you need `map` the value in `No` column to the `true/false` condition and use it for subsetting:

```
df[df.No.map(s)]

#  No   piece
#2  2   piece3
#3  3   piece4
```

---

```
df.No.map(s)

# 0    False
# 1    False
# 2     True
# 3     True
# Name: No, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is a much more pandathonic answer. I'm glad OP chose this.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thank you. Both answers are good for OP's purpose here.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to index into `s` using `df['No']`, then use the result as a mask on `df` itself:

```
df[s[df['No']].values]
```

The final mask needs to be extracted as an array using `values` because the duplicates in the index cause an error otherwise.

Comment: I think you need `df[s[df['No']].values]`. This gives an error. Not my down vote though.